# Partial update on boolean fields in Django not updating the field in Database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to update boolean fields using `PATCH` request and `partial-update` in DRF. However, only the name field gets updated and not the others

Model:

```py
class UserModel(models.CustomModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Serializer

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.CustomModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = (
            'id', 'name', 'enabled', 'admin'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

View and function

```py
class UserView(viewsets.CustomModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.users.for_company(company=self.request.company.pk)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return UserSerializer

    def update(self, request, id):
        try:
            instance = self.get_queryset().get(id=id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response('User not in DB', status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        if 'name' in request.data and self.get_queryset().filter(name=request.data['name']).exists():
            return Response('Duplicated user name', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Url

```py
urlpatterns = [ url(r'^(?P<id>${uuid})/$', UserView.as_view(
        {'patch': 'update'}), name='user-update') ]
```

Currently if I send a `PATCH` request with a user_id and the following data in the body, ONLY the name field gets updated in the DB.

```
name = user2
enabled = True
admin = True
```

However if I change the update method as follows, the DB gets updated correctly

```py
    def update(self, request, id):
        try:
            instance = self.get_queryset().get(id=id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response('User not in DB', status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        if 'name' in request.data and self.get_queryset().filter(name=request.data['name']).exists():
            return Response('Duplicated user name', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)

        if 'enabled' or 'admin' in request.data:
            instance.enabled = request.data.get('enabled', instance.enabled)
            instance.admin = request.data.get('admin', instance.admin)

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Is this the correct way to update the fields by modifying the instance? Shouldn't the Django partial-update method take care of this if I'm passing the other boolean fields in the request and update them correctly in the database?

I investigated further and understand that the serializer.save() calls an instance.save() under the hood, and validates the data, only the name fields gets through as validated data and not the other two boolean fields.

Comment: Don't your classes have to inherit from base classes?  `class UserModel(models.Model):`  `class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):` and  `class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):`

Comment: yes they do, using custom base Models/Serializers/ViewSets so I just chose to exclude those as arguments here, updated the code. :)